# Can handles become tamei?

Tags: tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, maseches-uktzin

The mishna [Uktzin 1:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Oktzin.1.1?lang=bi) discusses *yadot* (handles) for food, and how they מִטּמא ומְטמא ("contract uncleanness and convey uncleanness"). In his [commentary to that mishna](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Oktzin.1.1?lang=bi&with=Rambam&lang2=en), Rambam explains that the *yad* itself becomes *tamei* when the food does, and the food becomes *tamei* when its *yad* does. Additionally, the *yad* will convey *tumah* to anything it touches, if the *yad* and food are *tamei*.

This seems like a simple read of the mishna. On the other hand, [Tosfot on Ḥullin 128a s.v. *beheima beḥayyeha*](https://www.sefaria.org/Chullin.128a.16?lang=bi&with=Tosafot&lang2=en) says that *yadot* don't themselves become *tamei*. Instead, they transmit *tumah* to and from the food.

What is the basis of Tosfot's view (eg. how does it make sense with מִטּמא)? More importantly, is there a practical difference between these two views? It seems that according to both views, something *tamei* touching the combined *yad*/food anywhere will impart *tumah*, and anything touching *tamei* *yad*/food anywhere will itself become *tamei*. If the *yad* breaks off from the food, it's no longer a *yad* and shouldn't be susceptible to *tumah* according to either opinion.<sup>[source needed]</sup>

Comment: Can you use the yad to chotzeitz as an ohel? If it's mekabbel tumah then no. Can you use the yad as skhakh?

Comment: @DoubleAA It seems logical to me that the ability to transmit *tumah* would obviate such a use, but I'm not sure.